# Need advice with apartment wiring

Tags: wiring

Hello I would like to know what can happen if I connect a whole apartment that has a 12 awg internal wiring, using a 16 awg external wiring.

What are the issues or dangers that I may encounter?  and what do you recommend?

I plan to use just lights and small appliances @ 300w max

Recommended fuse for awg 12,14,16?

Finally whats the max recommended ampacity for awg 16?

Thanks

Comment: This ends up being more of a legal question than an EE question. Any good answer to your question would require knowing about your local electrical codes/ordinances beforehand. With that said, you _always, **always**_ use a fuse/circuit breaker that's rated flr the _lowest_ capacity wire in the circuit (in this case, the 16ga).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it blogs on Ome Improvememt

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "external wiring"? Are you talking about extension cords and outlet strips that you plug into the wall sockets? If so, you'll be fine as long as you don't exceed the total load rating of any given item.

Comment: @Scott. Sorry saw a similiar question here so I felt free to ask.

Comment: @TidyBloom If you mean you're using 16AWG extension cords _inside_ the apartment, that changes the question entirely & the answer becomes "just don't plug too much into one cord," rather than "don't burn down the whole building by overheating a 16AWG circuit in the walls." -- However, Scott Seidman was correct; this is not an electrical engineering problem nearly so much as a home improvement/everyday living question. Try this link for extension clrd safety info: http://www.askthebuilder.com/extension-cords-size-chart/

Comment: @Robherc.  To clarify.. The apartment has a 12awg within walls circuit,  and its being feed entirely by a 16 awg 10ft extension cord,  not the common internal every day extension we use for devices. Just wanted to know the risks that was it

Comment: @Dave. Yes an extension cord from 1 apartment wall socket to the Fuse box that feeds an entire old department. Sorry if wasnt clear

Comment: You don't say where you're located, but in any jurisdiction that I'm aware of, connecting the fusebox of one apartment to a wall socket in another would be completely illegal from a regulatory viewpoint, regardless of its technical merits. If anything were to go wrong, you would not only be completely liable for all damage caused, you might face criminal penalties as well. Only you can decide whether it's worth the risk. Just hire an electrician to wire it up correctly already. BTW, what happened to the *original* wiring to that fusebox?

Comment: @Dave. As I said in the other answer we own 4 apartments in our property,  the Old one that i've connected from the wall socket in my main apartment had a cancelled fuse box that we stopped using like 30 years ago so the old apartment was basically without lights and was render almost useless,  Thats why I did this, not sure how far the risks can go but all is in my property :)

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's your property -- you have it insured, right? If there's an accident/fire of any sort, and this illegal wiring is discovered, you will not receive any insurance payment at all. That's what I mean by "completely liable". I don't know what a "cancelled fusebox" is, but if it's just a matter of having the utility hook it up again, then go ahead. You're paying for the power either way.

Comment: Yes thats what I did hooked it up again so that old apartment will be of some use finally,  by "cancelled fuse box" i meant it was an unhooked fuse box without any power available until now. As you say its my power bill so the only risk here was the 16awg wire overload,  since the apartment was built with an optimal 20amps 12awg circuit.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to ask here, you need to ask yourself, "should I be messing with mains wiring?" Do local regulations **allow** you to mess with your wiring?

Regardless of what's in the apartment, as long as you fuse the **thinest** wire correctly, the wire will be safe from overload.

What's the ampacity for 16awg? Let me [look that up on wikipedia for you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge#Tables_of_AWG_wire_sizes). About 18A they reckon if you let it get to 90C, you can guess at half that for something you can touch, say 60C surface temperature.

They also suggest fusing a conductor with a wire 4 gagues down, so 20awg. Sounds a bit thick to me. Try google for some wiring installation regulations that pertain to your area.

Comment: Pretty detailed advice,  wasnt sure about the 60c awg 16 ampacity since wikipedia only shows it @ 90c, I must say I was succesfull doing this, every light seems to work fine as well as low amp devices. I've also read that the max ampacity should be @80% of wire capacity so for 16 awg max is 1.2kw and to be safe I shouldn't exceed 1kw with a fuse @ 10amps right? Correct if im wrong Thanks

Comment: In North American electrical codes, the ampacity of #14 wire, for normal house wiring, is 15 Amps.  #16 will be somewhat less - perhaps 9 amps or so.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a lawyer, nor do I play one on TV, but my advice is that unless you're a licensed electrician, you should hire the work done by one [competent licensed electrician] and, that way, steer clear of any liability you might incur by doing \$\style{color:red;font-size:100}{ANYTHING}\$ to, or with, the mains yourself.

The reason is that if anything untoward happens (like a fire, say) you're going to be the one who has to defend yourself in court and, make no mistake about it, even if you knew what you were doing, electrically, (which you don't, since you're asking questions here) the vulture insurance company(ies) would have a field day with you.

And, should anyone be hurt, you might as well resign yourself to the fact that when all the legal stuff has died down, your life as you knew it will be pretty much over. ):

Comment: Dont worry my friend,  lets say we have 4 apartments in our property so,  1of them is rather old thus suitable only for item storage only,  thats why I wanted to connect one of modern ones to the old one as long as everything is connected safely :)

Comment: Is the existing wiring malfunctioning in some way? Why not just repair the existing wiring and retain the original functionality?

Comment: Yes the old apartment wiring seems to work well,  I just found practical and easy to connect the entire apartment to the main one, since I'm just going to connect a few lights and 1 or 2 small appliances :)